# Operand '==' cannot be applied for operands of type bool and string

Tags: sql, linq

```
if (vehicleListOnly)
        {
            results = results.Where(x => x.IsOffer=="True");
        }
```

IsOffer is bit in Database.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error tells you the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsOffer` is a bool `true` not string `"True"`.  You could just do

```
...
results = results.Where(x => x.IsOffer);
...
```

Comment: I am new to programming. it worked. thanks for the fast response

Comment: Click the clear check mark and it will turn green.  [Here is a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) with instructions and a picture.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is you are comparing bool values like string, which is causing compiler to raise concern. Hence it is saying "==" can not be applied on operands booean(`IsOffer`) and string(`True`). Which is obvious if you compare two data, make sure they are of the same type else you ma end up with issue. 
You can use

```
results = results.Where(x => x.IsOffer == true);
```

Or

```
results = results.Where(x => x.IsOffer);
```

Both will work fine. Hope i was able to explain.